# Domaine - How does the Chancery work?

Tags: domaine

When a player takes a card from the Chancery, can he only take the top card, or can he look through the entire pile from the Chancery and picks a card he wants (except the one he just sold).

Comment: Just to save anyone else this trouble.  This isn't a question about Dominion :)  I wasted a bit of time looking for the Chancery card in Dominion just now.... It might be time to go to bed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [full rules](http://mayfairgames.com/game.php?id=85&stock=MFG4102&name=Domaine) on Mayfair Games site:

> Note: If you sell an action card, you may not chose to draw that card when you refill your hand to 3 cards at the end of your turn.  You may chose any other card in the Chancery, or draw from the action deck.